# Android Intent extras return null attributes

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

So I start off by creating a custom object "Book"

```
Book b = new Book(id, title.getText().toString(),authors , isbn.getText().toString(), "$9.99");
```

All of these parameters are defined and not null. Next I take the object "b" and put it into an Intent as follows:

```
resultIntent.putExtra(BOOK_RESULT_KEY, b);
```

Still good. Retrieving the object here gets exactly what was put in, expectedly:

```
Book test = (Book) resultIntent.getExtras().get(BOOK_RESULT_KEY);
```

Finish and return to parent activity with the intent as a result:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Off to the parent activity:

```
Book b = (Book) intent.getExtras().get(AddBookActivity.BOOK_RESULT_KEY);
```

Here lies the issue. All the attributes of this object book are there, except the authors[]. What I get is an array (authors[]) with the correct length, but each element in the array is now null. I am 100 percent positive it was there when it was placed into the intent. Why can I not get the contents of this array?

Comment: Does your Book class implement parcelable?

Comment: You can not directly pass the object in Intent. You need to pass it as `Bundle` and get it from `Bundle`.

Comment: have implemented Book class with parcelable?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your `Book` class `Parcelable` and then you can pass it as `Parcelable` array into `Bundle` and get it directly from `Bundle`.

Check out the [Simple Parcelable Example](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/using-android-parcel)

Assuming your code

```
  public class Book implements Parcelable{

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String authors;
    private String isbn;
    private String price;
    // Constructor
    public Student(String id, String title, String authors,String isbn,String price){
        this.id = id;
        this.title= title;
        this.authors = authors;
        this.isbn=isbn;
        this.price=price;
   }

    ......................................
       // Parcelling part
   public Book(Parcel in){
       String[] data = new String[5];

       in.readStringArray(data);
       this.id = data[0];
       this.title= data[1];
       this.authors= data[2];
       this.isbn= data[3];
       this.price= data[4];
   }

   @Оverride
   public int describeContents(){
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
       dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {this.id,
                                           this.title,
                                           this.authors,this.isbn,this.price});
   }
   public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
       public Book createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new Book(in); 
       }

       public Book[] newArray(int size) {
           return new Book[size];
       }
   };
 }
```

Now after creating Parcelable class you can pass data as below:

```
   resultIntent.putExtra(BOOK_RESULT_KEY,new Book(id, title.getText().toString(),authors , isbn.getText().toString(), "$9.99"));
```

Get the data from Bundle as below:

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

 Book b = (Book)data.getParcelable(AddBookActivity.BOOK_RESULT_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use book as implement Serialisable and getserialisable object in next activity.

Comment: If he done with Parcelable then what is problem? And why Serializable, if Android gives Parcelable?

Comment: both are same as functional but i'm doing it with using serialisable.parcelable is also good :)

Comment: i am sorry i am using it.but can you give me suggetion why we are not using serialisation.so i can improve it to parcelable..

Comment: Read http://blog.3pillarglobal.com/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-android-app-development